# Bash script reading input in loop

Tags: bash, loops, variables, input

I want to read bash script

e.g

```
test.sh input1 id1 name1 input2 id2 name2 input3 id3 name3
```

I want to read input into loop and assign group of three parameters to local variable and run different command e.g

```
for var in "$@"   
    do
    input=$var
    id=$var+1
    name=$var+2
    rawFastq=${input}
     echo "input is" $input
     echo "id" $id
     echo "name is" $name
   Rscript "$input"/script1.R ID name

done
```

How do I go to the next command line parameter.  `$var+1` or adding counter and then doing `${i+1}` doesn't work?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: "get next cmd-line param" with `shift`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to iterate over the elements of the user's parameters, just like in any other programming language. For example:

```
args=("$@")
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#args[@]} ]; do
  input=${args[$i]}
  i=$[$i+1]
  id=${args[$i]}
  i=$[$i+1]
  name=${args[$i]}
  i=$[$i+1]

  Rscript $input/script1.R $id $name
done
```